# In Risk, what if territory cards earned by invading finish?

Tags: risk

We are playing Risk and after getting 60 extra troops, there are no territory cards left, so no one able to create new sets to exchange. Should we re-flush the cards and continue building sets?

Comment: What do you mean there are no territory cards left? Are you including the cards that have already been traded in?

Comment: Rule book has no indication that the traded-in cards can be earned again so we don't use them after they are treaded.

Answer (score 6):

This is not explicit in [the rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/risk.pdf). But common sense kicks in.

When:

- The rules mention a trade in, no discard or remove from game.
- The rules mention that each set has a higher unit value and there is no end mentioned of the set.

So reusing is more logical than the set ending. So you can safely assume that you can reuse the traded in cards.

Comment: It does say to keep cards that have been traded in under the board so I don't think it is that straight forward.

Comment: I would agree with this answer.  The continuing increasing value of turned in sets seems central the the risk in Risk.  Without sets being cashed in, too easy for the game to go on forever.  Seems like your group is playing too conservatively, I don't remember a game lasting long enough to encounter this issue.